# Why does it say this--> TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Content is just a text file

```
tokens = content.split()
topics = [e for (n, x) in enumerate(tokens) for (n2, x2) in enumerate(tokens) for (i, e) in enumerate(tokens) if any(x2.isdigit()) if '.' in x if re.findall('\D+', x) if n < i < n2]
```

I dont understand how I am iterating through a `bool` and also is there a more concise and faster way of doing this list comprehension?

Comment: We can't tell you if there is a faster/better way to do something if you haven't told us what you're trying to do. Can you show an example input and your expected output?

Comment: You should probably include a snippet that reproduces the problem and defines al the variables.

Comment: What is the purpose of this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from - `any(x2.isdigit())` , I am guessing `x2` is a string, so `x2.isdigit()` returns a `bool` , you cannot use `any()` function on it.

Try using without the `any()` function to check if x2 is a number -

```
if x2.isdigit()
```

If what you want to check is whether `x2` has a digit in it or not, you can try -

```
if any(i.isdigit() for i in x2)
```

Though I do not know what you are trying to do, so cannot check if the other logic is good or not.

[`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function is used on a **iterable** (lists or generator expression, etc) , to check if any of them is True.

Comment: x2.isdigit() returns true if the string is a digit. any(x2.isdigit()) returns true if there are any digits in the string

Comment: also this isnt homework

Comment: no, `any(x2.isdigit())` results in the error you are getting. Try the second if i added.

Comment: thanks I didnt see you added that.

Comment: also, the code takes forever to run and Im planning on doing a bunch of these :/

Comment: I cannot help unless I understand what you are trying to do